# refreshing content using jquery works only once

Tags: jquery, partial-page-refresh

I am using this jquery function:

```
$(function() {
  $("#refresh").click(function() {
     $("#category_dialog").load("<?php echo $category; ?>")
  })
});
```

i am using as well a link with the id="refresh" problem is it reloads the content only once, when i click it second time it doesnt refresh and i know there were changes made.
Thanks!

Comment: just a shot into the dark: replace `.click()` with `.live('click', function(){})`. Just in case you replace that element aswell.

Comment: by some weird reason after i hit refresh 2 times. some of my other jquery plugins break. like tabs and some code i use to submit the forms. you have any idea why ?

Comment: What is #refresh, a link, button or some other element?  For the problems with other plugins and live(), try these debugging steps:  1) Try different browsers  2) Try replacing your load() with a static html url on your server.  3) Replace the load() with .html("Hello, world!")  4) Try clearing your html before calling load() to refresh with .html("")  5) Try moving your #refresh element out of #category_dialog

Comment: refresh is a link. i tired different browsers and i get the same thing. next i tried to load a statc html url - when i hit refresh second time it doesnt display the modifications very weird (it worked twice with the php generated file). 3 works. 4. i don't understand exactly what you mean. moving the refresh link outside #category_dialog gets me the same result as in other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check that you don't duplicate your container ID's.

Try switching to classes:

```
$(function() {
  $(".refresh").click(function() {
     $(".category_dialog").load("<?php echo $category; ?>")
  })
});
```

If this works then you know there must be duplicate ID's in the content that has been loaded.

Answer (score 3):

Is the `#refresh` element part of the code that gets reloaded? If so, you need to rebind the click event, or just use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/), which is slower but sometimes it comes in handy if not abused.

It would look something like:

```
$(function() {
    $("#refresh").live('click',function() {
        $("#category_dialog").load("<?php echo $category; ?>");
    });
});
```

EDIT: One thing I noticed is you don't end all your statements with `;`. You might check for parsing errors.

Comment: yes work but as you say if not abused :) if i click refresh more than 2 times - somethin weird happens. i use jquery to submit my form. and submit button does not work any more -- as well as my tabs. wish i know why...i even moved the refresh link outside the category_dialog id and still i get the same thing..

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure your element with id=refresh exists only once in DOM.
2. make sure its(#refresh) is outside #category_dialog. if its inside #category_dialog then your php code should must return the #refresh element again, also u have to rebind your #refresh (to avoid rebinding again use .live())